# ERROR MicroBatchExecution - PySpark: Writing dataframe to Elasticsearch

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to write a stream to Elasticsearch using PySpark. I have two dataframes that I read from Kafka and join into `df_joined`. Printing `df_joined` to the terminal shows the correct columns and values.
Once I try to write it to Elasticsearch (on localhost:9200) using this code:

```
spark_session = SparkSession.builder.appName("spark-test").config("spark.jars.packages", "org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.1.2,org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-hadoop:8.5.3").getOrCreate()
df1 = ... 
df2 = ... # For df1 and df2 I do .select(from_json(col('value), schema)) 
df_joined = df1.join(df2, df1.fk == d2.pk)
query = df_joined \
    .writeStream \
    .outputMode("append") \
    .format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql") \
    .option("es.resource", "name_of_index/name_of_type") \
    .option("es.mapping.id", "id") \
    .option("es.spark.sql.streaming.sink.log.enabled", False) \
    .option("checkpointLocation", "/tmp/es_checkpoint") \
    .start()
query.awaitTermination()
```

I use:

- elastic-search-hadoop version 8.5.3
- PySpark version 3.3.1

I get the following error/stack trace:

```
22/12/28 00:41:48 ERROR MicroBatchExecution: Query [id = 3b9b239f-bd38-43e0-820a-6d8fdac56e79, runId = e4869668-2e3c-4e8e-a6be-6c111a832812] terminated with error
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(Lorg/apache/spark/sql/SparkSession;Lorg/apache/spark/sql/execution/QueryExecution;Lscala/Function0;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.streaming.EsSparkSqlStreamingSink.addBatch(EsSparkSqlStreamingSink.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runBatch$17(MicroBatchExecution.scala:666)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$6(SQLExecution.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:169)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:95)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:779)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runBatch$16(MicroBatchExecution.scala:664)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:375)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken$(ProgressReporter.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.runBatch(MicroBatchExecution.scala:664)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runActivatedStream$2(MicroBatchExecution.scala:256)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:375)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken$(ProgressReporter.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1(MicroBatchExecution.scala:219)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProcessingTimeExecutor.execute(TriggerExecutor.scala:67)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.runActivatedStream(MicroBatchExecution.scala:213)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.$anonfun$runStream$1(StreamExecution.scala:307)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:779)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:285)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:208)
Exception in thread "stream execution thread for [id = 3b9b239f-bd38-43e0-820a-6d8fdac56e79, runId = e4869668-2e3c-4e8e-a6be-6c111a832812]" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(Lorg/apache/spark/sql/SparkSession;Lorg/apache/spark/sql/execution/QueryExecution;Lscala/Function0;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.streaming.EsSparkSqlStreamingSink.addBatch(EsSparkSqlStreamingSink.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runBatch$17(MicroBatchExecution.scala:666)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$6(SQLExecution.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:169)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:95)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:779)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runBatch$16(MicroBatchExecution.scala:664)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:375)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken$(ProgressReporter.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.runBatch(MicroBatchExecution.scala:664)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runActivatedStream$2(MicroBatchExecution.scala:256)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:375)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken$(ProgressReporter.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1(MicroBatchExecution.scala:219)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProcessingTimeExecutor.execute(TriggerExecutor.scala:67)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.runActivatedStream(MicroBatchExecution.scala:213)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.$anonfun$runStream$1(StreamExecution.scala:307)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:779)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:285)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:208)
```

**What I have tried**

- I have tried downgrading PySpark to version 3.2.0 (based on an accepted SO answer)
- When creating the SparkSession I have tried to change `org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-hadoop:8.5.3` to `org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-spark-20_2.11:8.5.3`

*edit:*

- Koedlt's answer was very helpful to understand the problem better but unfortunately downgrading the version to 2.3.0 did not solve the problem as the integration with Kafka failed.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the most interesting piece of your error, you see the following:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(Lorg/apache/spark/sql/SparkSession;Lorg/apache/spark/sql/execution/QueryExecution;Lscala/Function0;)

So it's not finding a method of `SQLExecution` called `withNewExecutionId` that has a `SparkSession`, a `QueryExecution` and a `Function` as input. Let's have a look at that method in Spark's source code.

In [version 3.3.1](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/fbbcf9434ac070dd4ced4fb9efe32899c6db12a9/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/SQLExecution.scala#L58-L64), we see the following function signature:

```
def withNewExecutionId[T](
      queryExecution: QueryExecution,
      name: Option[String] = None)(body: => T): T
```

This explains why you're getting a `NoSuchMethodError`: there is no method with the function signature you're expecting!

Now, let's look at the dependencies of your artifact in [Maven Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch-hadoop/8.5.3). For Spark, we're seeing this:

[image]

with the left column being the dependency version and the right column the newest stable update to that dependency. Let's have a look at the dependency version, 2.3.0.

In [version 2.3.0](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/992447fb30ee9ebb3cf794f2d06f4d63a2d792db/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/SQLExecution.scala#L55-L61), we see the following function signature:

```
def withNewExecutionId[T](
      sparkSession: SparkSession,
      queryExecution: QueryExecution)(body: => T): T
```

That looks like what we're expecting! A `SparkSession`, a `QueryExecution` and a `Function` as an input.

**Solution**: It seems like this artifact requires you to use Spark 2.3.0 and is not compatible with newer versions the way you're using it right now. I don't know this artifact per se, so maybe there are ways around this. But try it out with version 2.3.0 and see what happens :)